# r - best function to select combinations of columns in dataset

Tags: r, combinations

Let's say I want to subset my dataset `df` (m rows x n cols) always taking the first column and all the possible combinations of the other columns.

```
df = as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*1000, 1, .5), nrow = 10, ncol=5))
```

So far I created the following function:

```
Mycomb = function(elements){
  n = length(elements)
  list = c()
  for (i in 1:n){
    list = append(list,c(combn(x = elements, m = i, simplify = F)))
  }

  return(list)
}
```

I generate all the combinations of the columns 2:5

```
combinations = Mycomb(c(2,3,4,5))
```

and then subset the dataset in a loop, with the following code:

```
for (i in 1:length(combinations)){

  colOK = c(1,unlist(combinations[[i]], use.names=FALSE))
  cat("Selected columns: ", toString(colOK), "\n")
  print(df[,colOK])

}
```

This is the best code I could come up with, even if it does not look very clean. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: If your columns are interchangeable, they must be the same data type, so you will probably get a substantial speed-up by using matrices instead of data frames. And it seems like your for loop is just printing the selection - is that really your goal? You don't want to save them in a list or something?

Comment: Thanks Gregor, indeed printing here was just an example. I then do something else, but I limited the question to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be greatly simplified, starting with the function `Mycomb`.
Note that I have added an extra argument, `simplify`, that defaults to `FALSE`.

```
Mycomb <- function(elements, simplify = FALSE){
  result <- lapply(seq_along(elements), function(m)
    combn(elements, m, simplify = simplify))

  result
}

combinations <- Mycomb(2:5)
```

Now if you want all the subsets of `df`, use a double `lapply` on the result `combinations`.

```
sub_df_list <- lapply(combinations, function(inx_list)
    lapply(inx_list, function(i) df[, c(1, i)])
  )

length(sub_df_list[[1]])
#[1] 4
```

So the first member of the results list has a total of `4` sub data frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very useful. Once I do that, how can I later access in a loop to every single generated sub_dataframe? Which indexing should I use?

Comment: You must use **two** indexes. For instance, `sub_df_list[[1]][[2]]`.